# ArrayFire frame search algorithm crash

Tags: search, cuda, segmentation-fault, frame, arrayfire

I am new to ArrayFire and CUDA development in general, I just started using ArrayFire a couple of days ago after failing miserably using Thrust.
I am building an ArrayFire-based algorithm that is supposed to search a single 32x32 pixel frame in a database of a couple hundred thousand 32x32 frames that are stored into device memory.
At first I initialize a matrix that has 1024 + 1 pixels as rows (I need an extra one to keep a frame group id) and a predefined number (this case 1000) of frames, indexed by coloumn.

Here's the function that performs the search, if I uncomment "pixels_uint32 = device_frame_ptr[pixel_group_idx];" the program crashes. The pointer seems to be valid so I do not understand why this happens. Maybe there is something I do not know regarding accessing device memory in this way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arrayfire.h>

#include "utils.h"

using namespace af;
using namespace std;

/////////////////////////// CUDA settings ////////////////////////////////
#define TEST_DEBUG false
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES  1000 // maximum (2499999 frames) X (1024 + 1 pixels per frame) x (2 bytes per pixel) = 5.124.997.950 bytes (~ 5GB)
#define BLOB_FINGERPRINT_SIZE 1024 //32x32

//percentage of macroblocks that should match: 0.9 means 90%
#define MACROBLOCK_COMPARISON_OVERALL_THRESHOLD 768 //1024 * 0.75
//////////////////////// End of CUDA settings ////////////////////////////

array search_frame(array d_db_vec) 
{
    try {
        uint number_of_uint32_for_frame = BLOB_FINGERPRINT_SIZE / 2;

        // create one-element array to hold the result of the computation
        array frame_found(1,MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES, u32);
        frame_found = 0;

        gfor (array frame_idx, MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES) {

            // get the blob id it's the last coloumn of the matrix
            array blob_id = d_db_vec(number_of_uint32_for_frame, frame_idx);  // addressing with (pixel_idx, frame_idx)

            // define some hardcoded pixel to search for             
            uint8_t searched_r = 0x0;
            uint8_t searched_g = 0x3F;
            uint8_t searched_b = 0x0;

            uint8_t b1 = 0;
            uint8_t g1 = 0;
            uint8_t r1 = 0;

            uint8_t b2 = 0;
            uint8_t g2 = 0;
            uint8_t r2 = 0;

            uint32_t sum1 = 0;
            uint32_t sum2 = 0;

            uint32_t *device_frame_ptr   = NULL;
            uint32_t pixels_uint32       = 0;            

            uint pixel_match_counter = 0;

            //uint pixel_match_counter = 0;
            array frame = d_db_vec(span, frame_idx);
            device_frame_ptr = frame.device<uint32_t>();

            for (uint pixel_group_idx = 0; pixel_group_idx < number_of_uint32_for_frame; pixel_group_idx++) {
                // test to see if the whole matrix is traversed 
                // d_db_vec(pixel_group_idx, frame_idx) = 0;

                /////////////////////////////// PROBLEMATIC CODE ///////////////////////////////////
                pixels_uint32 = 0x7E007E0;
                //pixels_uint32 = device_frame_ptr[pixel_group_idx]; //why does this crash the program?
                // if I uncomment the above line the program tries to copy the u32 frame into the pixels_uint32 variable
                // something goes wrong, since the pointer device_frame_ptr is not NULL and the elements should be there judging by the lines above
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // splitting the first pixel into its components
                b1 = (pixels_uint32 & 0xF8000000) >> 27;   //(input & 11111000000000000000000000000000)
                g1 = (pixels_uint32 & 0x07E00000) >> 21;   //(input & 00000111111000000000000000000000)
                r1 = (pixels_uint32 & 0x001F0000) >> 16;   //(input & 00000000000111110000000000000000)

                // splitting the second pixel into its components
                b2 = (pixels_uint32 & 0xF800) >> 11;       //(input & 00000000000000001111100000000000)
                g2 = (pixels_uint32 & 0x07E0) >> 5;        //(input & 00000000000000000000011111100000)
                r2 = (pixels_uint32 & 0x001F);             //(input & 00000000000000000000000000011111)

                // checking if they are a match
                sum1 = abs(searched_r - r1) + abs(searched_g - g1) + abs(searched_b - b1);
                sum2 = abs(searched_r - r2) + abs(searched_g - g2) + abs(searched_b - b2);

                // if they match, increment the local counter
                pixel_match_counter = (sum1 <= 16) ? pixel_match_counter + 1 : pixel_match_counter;
                pixel_match_counter = (sum2 <= 16) ? pixel_match_counter + 1 : pixel_match_counter;             
            }

            bool is_found = pixel_match_counter > MACROBLOCK_COMPARISON_OVERALL_THRESHOLD;  
            // write down if the frame is a match or not        
            frame_found(0,frame_idx) = is_found ? frame_found(0,frame_idx) : blob_id;
        }

       // test to see if the whole matrix is traversed - this has to print zeroes
    if (TEST_DEBUG)
            print(d_db_vec);

        // return the matches array
    return frame_found;

    } catch (af::exception& e) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        throw;
    }
}

// make 2 green pixels
uint32_t make_test_pixel_group() {
    uint32_t b1 = 0x0;        //11111000000000000000000000000000
    uint32_t g1 = 0x7E00000;  //00000111111000000000000000000000
    uint32_t r1 = 0x0;        //00000000000111110000000000000000

    uint32_t b2 = 0x0;        //00000000000000001111100000000000
    uint32_t g2 = 0x7E0;      //00000000000000000000011111100000
    uint32_t r2 = 0x0;        //00000000000000000000000000011111

    uint32_t green_pix = b1 | g1 | r1 | b2 | g2 | r2;

    return green_pix;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    info();

    /////////////////////////////////////// CREATE THE DATABASE ///////////////////////////////////////
    uint number_of_uint32_for_frame = BLOB_FINGERPRINT_SIZE / 2;

    array d_db_vec(number_of_uint32_for_frame + 1,   // fingerprint size + 1 extra u32 for blob id
                   MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES,             // number of frames
                   u32);                             // type of elements is 32-bit unsigned integer (unsigned) with the configuration RGBRGB (565565)

    if (TEST_DEBUG == true) {
        for (uint frame_idx = 0; frame_idx < MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES; frame_idx++) {       
            for (uint pix_idx = 0; pix_idx < number_of_uint32_for_frame; pix_idx++) {
                d_db_vec(pix_idx, frame_idx) = make_test_pixel_group();  // fill everything with green :D
            }
        }
    } else {
        d_db_vec = rand(number_of_uint32_for_frame + 1, MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES);
    }

    cout << "Setting blob ids. \n\n";
    for (uint frame_idx = 0; frame_idx < MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES; frame_idx++) {
        // set the blob id to 123456
        d_db_vec(number_of_uint32_for_frame, frame_idx) = 123456;  // blob_id = 123456
    }

    if (TEST_DEBUG)
        print(d_db_vec);

    cout << "Done setting blob ids. \n\n";

    //////////////////////////////////// CREATE THE SEARCHED FRAME ///////////////////////////////////

    // to be done, for now we use the hardcoded values at line 37-39 to simulate the searched pixel:
    //37        uint8_t searched_r = 0x0;
    //38        uint8_t searched_g = 0x3F;
    //39        uint8_t searched_b = 0x0;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////// SEARCH /////////////////////////////////////////////    
    clock_t timer = startTimer();    
    for (int i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
        array frame_found = search_frame(d_db_vec);

        if (TEST_DEBUG)
            print(frame_found);
    }
    stopTimer(timer);

    return 0;
}
```

### Here is the console output with the line commented:

arrayfire/examples/helloworld$ ./helloworld

ArrayFire v1.9.1   (64-bit Linux, build 9af23ea)

License: Server (27000@server.accelereyes.com)

CUDA toolkit 5.0, driver 304.54

GPU0 Tesla C2075, 5376 MB, Compute 2.0

Memory Usage: 5312 MB free (5376 MB total)

Setting blob ids.

Done setting blob ids.

Time: 0.03 seconds.

---

### Here is the console output with the line uncommented:

arrayfire/examples/helloworld$ ./helloworld

ArrayFire v1.9.1   (64-bit Linux, build 9af23ea)

License: Server (27000@server.accelereyes.com)

CUDA toolkit 5.0, driver 304.54

GPU0 Tesla C2075, 5376 MB, Compute 2.0

Memory Usage: 5312 MB free (5376 MB total)

Setting blob ids.

Done setting blob ids.

Segmentation fault

---

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue. I really tried everything but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of arrayfire. I see that you have [posted on AccelerEyes forums](http://forums.accelereyes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=25655) as well, but I am posting here to clear up some common issues with your code.*

1. Do not use .device(), .host(), .scalar() inside gfor loop. This will cause divergences inside the GFOR loop, and GFOR was not designed for this.
2. You can not index into a device pointer. The pointer refers to a location **on the GPU**. When you do  `device_frame_ptr[pixel_group_idx];`, the system is looking for the equivalent position **on the CPU**. This is the reason for your segmentation fault.
3. Use vectorized code. For example, you don't need the inner for loop of the gfor. Instead of doing `b1 = (pixels_uint32 & 0xF8000000) >> 27;` inside a for loop, You can do `array B1 = (frame & 0xF800000000) >> 27;`. i.e. instead of getting data back to CPU and using a for loop, you are doing the entire operation inside the GPU.
4. Don't use if-else  or ternary operators inside GFOR. These cause divergences again. For example, `pixel_match_counter = sum(sum1 <= 16) + sum(sum2 < 16);` and `found(0, found_idx) = is_found * found(0, found_idx) + (1 - is_found) * blob_id`.

I have answered the particular problem you are facing. If you have any follow up questions, please follow up on our forums and / or our support email. Stackoverflow is good for asking a specific question, but not to debug your entire program.

Comment: Hi, your colleague Chris already gave me some deatils as well. What is still not clear for me is point 4. You say not to use formulations like this: pixel_match_counter = sum(sum1 <= 16) + sum(sum2 < 16); but on ArrayFire documentation however, I found this (http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/page_gfor.htm):  

"For instance, the block of code above can be converted to run as follows, without error:

Example 1: Solution

   gfor (array k, m) {
      array condition = (k > 1); // good
      A(span,k) = (!condition).as(f32) * A(span,k) + condition.as(f32) * (k + 1);
   }"

Comment: Also Chris said I could do something like this:
             
            array sum1c = sum(sum1 <= 16);
            array sum2c = sum(sum2 <= 16);

          
            array pixel_match_counter = sum1c + sum2c;
            array is_found = pixel_match_counter > MACROBLOCK_COMPARISON_OVERALL_THRESHOLD;

So how is it better to do after all?

Comment: Formulations like "array condition = (k > 1);" are not allowed inside gfor loops after all?

Comment: @DevtelSoftware As mentioned in the email, this is not a place to discuss tangential topics. I have answered your questions regarding the segmentation fault. Please follow up all other questions on accelereyes forums.